# Trouble binding complex input to variable, efficiently

Tags: angularjs, json, binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new to Angular and trying to learn. I am trying to find a way to bind some Quantities with their IDs. Here is my template:

```
"<div class='tableBorder'><label> <input ng-model='" + modelngQTY + "'  type='number' name='{{value.DetailID}}' /> {{value.Text | lowercase}}  </label> </div>"
```

The modelngQTY is:

```
modelngQTY = "selectedOptions[value.CustomID].Details[value.DetailID].QTY";
```

Unfortunately the object that gets generated with this code is:

```
{"36":{"Details":{"107":{"QTY":2323232},"108":{"QTY":232323}}}}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 {"36":{"Details":[{DetailID: "107", "QTY":2323232},{DetailID: "108","QTY":232323}]}}
```

Here is a side-by-side visual of the two. I want the one on the left:
[image]

The version on the right is terribly hard to loop through with ng-repeat. I have all the data obviously I just cant figure out how to write the model. I have tried {} and [], as well as a lot of different ngmodel versions. The best I could get was the version on the right.

I have already done a lot of googling and there are tons of resources on how to filter and play with ng-options for ng-repeat but I couldn't find hardly anything about INSERTING the data into the model in a good format.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to this exists at http://plnkr.co/edit/9wMZAD?p=info.

These map functions

```
 vm.endingStructure= _.map(vm.beginningStructure, function(object, value) {
    var newStructure = {};
    newStructure[value] = {
      Details: _.map(object.Details, function(qtyObject, value) {
        var arrayStructure = {
          DetailID: value,
          QTY:qtyObject.QTY
        };
        return arrayStructure;
      })
    };
    return newStructure;
  });
```

turns `{ "36": { "Details": { "107": { "QTY": 2323232 }, "108": { "QTY": 232323 } } } }` into     `[ { "36": { "Details": [ { "DetailID": "107", "QTY": 2323232 }, { "DetailID": "108", "QTY": 232323 } ] } } ]`

Comment: this looks like exactly what I'm looking for!!! Thank you! Sorry if this is a stupid question but if I change newStructure its not going to bind to the old data is it?

Comment: Correct, your original data will not change unless you assign the map to the variable containing the original data.

Comment: If you have to call an API to update the data in the original structure you can bind the ng-repeat html code to this new structure and in the update call just deconstruct to the original on the api call. You can make a service to handle the new/old version construction.